# How to change layout of form title bar to RTL?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Thanks to the following script I can change the whole form layout to RTL.

```
procedure TfrmTest.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
    Params.ExStyle := WS_EX_LEFT or WS_EX_LTRREADING or WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR
     or WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL;
    {WS_EX_LEFT to set the text caption to the right,
    use WS_EX_RIGHT to set the caption to the left}
end;
```

results:
[image]

But How can I change **only** the form title bar and not whole controls inside the form?

Comment: What language are you targeting? What do you want to happen to the caption bar widgets? The buttons and the system menu icon.

Comment: I'm using a right to left language and want caption bar items to suite my language. Forms caption must go to right and buttons go to left (just opposite direction in English and other LTR languages).

Comment: Host a borderless form.

Comment: I don't understand. What you mean by host?

Comment: @SAM - What I meant was to parent a LTR layout form in the RTL layout form, by manual docking f.i. However your solution is better.

Comment: However, the controls are not properly redrawn when resizing the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've searched MSDN and found that this is a mirroring problem. It's solved by adding `WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT` to `Params.ExStyle`:

```
procedure TfrmTest.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  ... 
  Params.ExStyle := ... or WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT;
end;
```